# Is there a way to know if ExecutorService ended successfully?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

When an exception happens, I call shutdownNow() on my ExecutorService. I thought that isTerminated() would give me the success status, being true when all threads finished, and false otherwise. But I always get true, no matter what. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutdownNow()` will stop tasks that are waiting.  If you want the currently waiting threads to execute, then try using `shutdown()`

javadoc on it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that isTerminated() is always returning true because you are calling `shutdownNow()` rather than `shutdown()` **and**, as per the API documentation for `shutdownNow()`:

> ... typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt()

Hence it sounds like your tasks are all responding immediately to the interrupt attempt causing them to complete immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs say, "`isTerminated` is never true unless either shutdown or shutdownNow was called first". So it only tells if the tasks ended, not whether they were successful. You could have a flag, like an `AtomicBoolean` and toggle its state just before successful completion. This way you would use methods of `ExecutorService` to check if the task finished and your flag to check if it finished successfully.